# Padding between two images

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create space between two images, but they both use the same div name. Is it possible to make space between each other?

html:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="skillsection">
        <h1> Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5"> 
            <div class="image-container">
              <img src="Images/back6.jpg" alt="my image" class="img-about">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img src="Images/back6.jpg" alt="my image" class="img-about">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <h3> &larr; &nbsp; here </h3>
                <br>
                <h1><span class="five">My</span> <span class="four">Work</span></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried :

```
.image-container img{
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.image-container + .image-container{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

but cant seem to create space between each other

Comment: There is clearly some CSS not included here, because these images would not be side by side at all with just this, since `<div>` tags default to `display:block`.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or some similar type of CSS/JS? If so, you might want to put containers around each image-container like this: `<div class="container"><div class="col-5"><div class="image-container"> ... </div></div></div> `

Comment: Maybe investigate margin, since you are trying to add space between two blocks. It also seems you´re using twitter bootstrap or something similar.

Comment: ye i am using bootstrap 4

Comment: Why do you need divs around the images?

Comment: Iam creating a border and then hover effect etc

Comment: You don't need divs to do that.

Comment: http://findmatthew.com/ If you scroll down to the project section of this site, this is what i want to try and create

Comment: if you are tryinig to do something like what you describe maybe you should ckeck [bootstrap Cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/)

Comment: Thank you @OmarYafer i will try my best and see what i can do , trying to do the overlay right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
.image-container:first-of-type {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

This will affect only the first one, and the container, not the image...

Comment: That did not work , i will update my full code ontop

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you´re trying to accomplish.

```css
.image-container {
  border: 1px solid gray; /**This is not necessary I just added it for fun*/
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skillsection">
      <h1> Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="https://www.visitmexico.com/sites/default/files/field/image/2017/03/puebla_destinos-principales_puebla_int_2.jpg" alt="my image" class="img-about">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="https://www.visitmexico.com/sites/default/files/field/image/2017/03/puebla_destinos-principales_puebla_int_2.jpg" alt="my image" class="img-about">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <h3> &larr; &nbsp; here </h3>
        <br>
        <h1><span class="five">My</span> <span class="four">Work</span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You don´t actually need to add a space between the two images. If you´re using twitter bootstrap there is an space already added there. It´s the gutter space. As you can see all I did was ensure that the image only uses up to 100% of its parent´s width which is .image-container. The frameowrk will handle the rest.

Also please do refer to this part of the documentation: [Boostrap Grid System](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)